# Using "Reflection" to get int from another class isn't working

Tags: c#, reflection, int

**EDIT: I found the source of the error. I called `classTwo()` with `type` string pointing to a string, not an integer.**

So I'm trying to get an int from another class using Reflection.

It works when I get a string from another class, but not when I try to get an int.

Here is my code:

```
class classOne //In its own file (classOne.cs)
{
    public int myInt = 5;
    public string myString = "Hello World";
    new classTwo(this, "myInt").show(); //classTwo is actually a form.
}

class classTwo //In its own file (classTwo.cs)
{
    classOne frm;
    int kind1;
    string kind2;
    string type;

    public classTwo(classOne frm, string type)
    {
        this.frm = frm;
        this.type = type;
    }
    //Doesn't work:
    this.kind1 = Convert.ToInt32(this.frm.GetType().GetField(this.type).GetValue(this.frm));
    //Works:
    this.kind2 = Convert.ToString(this.frm.GetType().GetField("myString").GetValue(this.frm));
}
```

This doesn't work. It works when I use `Convert.ToString`, but when I use this, it throws an error when I run it:

---

**FormatException was Unhandled**

Input string was not in a correct format.

---

Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong, and give an explained fix (if possible)?

Comment: I think this is a canonical example of why chaining your methods together is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Your code works for me.  Show us an http://sscce.org/

Comment: Is this just experimentation with reflection for the sake of learning? I would discourage the use of reflection for solving this type of problems in general.

Comment: @ByteBlast I said this was my stripped down code. My actual code is much more compilcated.

Comment: @SLaks There, I edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly

```
class classOne //In its own file (classOne.cs)
{
    public int myInt = 5;
    public string myString = "Hello World";

    public void test()
    {
        var obj = new classTwo(this, "myInt");
        obj.test();

    }

}

class classTwo //In its own file (classTwo.cs)
{
    classOne frm;
    int kind1;
    string kind2;
    string type;

    public classTwo(classOne frm, string type)
    {
        this.frm = frm;
        this.type = type;
    }
    //Doesn't work:

    public void test()
    {
        //Doesn't work:
        this.kind1 = Convert.ToInt32(this.frm.GetType().GetField(this.type).GetValue(this.frm));


        this.kind2 = Convert.ToString(this.frm.GetType().GetField("myString").GetValue(this.frm));
    }
}
```

Comment: After thoroughly searching for the source of this madness, I found the problem. When I'm calling `classTwo(classOne frm, string type)`, the `type` I use, is actually a string, not an int. If that makes sense.

Thanks, anyway!